# Wpf - Drop shadow disappears

Tags: wpf, shadow, effect

I created a window with no style and added a custom border. I need my window to drop a shadow.

```
<Border BorderBrush="#000000 "           
                    BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" Width="400" 
                            Height="400" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    CornerRadius="10, 10, 0, 0"
                    Background="Black">
                        <Border.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" Direction="320" 
                                    ShadowDepth="5" Opacity="1" BlurRadius="5" />
                        </Border.Effect></Border>
```

But my shadow disappears when I set the width and height like this :

```
Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                    AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=Width}"
```

Help me find a solution please. Thanks

Comment: Fixed by adding another border inside of this one with Margin 5 and setting the external Border Thickness="0"

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't have the full scope of your solution, I must assume that the Border is within a ControlTemplate that is assigned to the Style of the Window.  Remember that if you are going to apply a DropShadowEffect to the root window you need to pad it otherwise you won't see it.  Apply Padding="10" to Border and you should see it.

Answer (score 0):

Try To add on the X & Y Thickness of the Shadow to your Windows dimensions

Answer (score 0):

Don't apply effects on the root visuals! In this case, they apply to all children down visual tree and will be cause of reducing performance.
Use the next pattern:

```
<Grid x:Name="RootWindowGrid">
   <Border x:Name="BorderWithEffect" Margin="5">
      <Border.Effect>
         <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" Direction="320" ShadowDepth="5" Opacity="1" BlurRadius="5" />
       </Border.Effect>
   </Border>

   <Border x:Name="RootBorder_ForAll_Another_Window_Visuals" Margin="5"/>
</Grid>
```

Margin depends on effect intensivity.